Question about conditional probability and wording
The question is: A coin is tossed 3 times. Find the probability that all are heads if it is known that 2 of them are heads.
What exactly does it mean by "2 of them are heads?" When working out the denominator of the conditional probability formula, am I finding the probability of exactly 2 heads or the probability of at least 2 heads or something like (1/2 * 1/2 * 1 *3C2), that is, getting two heads and then not caring what the mystery last toss is?
Any help greatly appreciated!

The probability that all are heads given that exactly 2 are heads is zero.  So the only nontrivial intepretation is that you want to compute the probability that all are heads given that two or more are heads.

"At least 2 heads" or "getting two heads and then not caring what the mystery last toss is": these two are the same events.

You toss three coins. Now someone tells you that there is at least two head, but you don't know which coins are head. You have to take that into account.
First method: Counting
Since there are only 3 coins, there are 8 possibilities.  There is only one possibility with 3 head : HHH. And there are three possibilities with 2 head: HHT, HTH and THH.
Possibilities of three head : 1
Possibilities of at least two head : 4
Probability of three head knowing there are at least two: $\frac14$
Second method: Combinatoric
Tossing a fair coin is a binomial process.
$$P(\text{3 head}) = {3 \choose 3} \left(\frac12\right)^3\left(\frac12\right)^0=\frac18$$
$$P(\text{exactly 2 head}) = {3 \choose 2} \left(\frac12\right)^2\left(\frac12\right)^1=\frac38$$
Finally conditionnal probability
$$P(\text{3 head}| \text{at least 2 head}) = \frac{\frac18}{\frac18+\frac38} = \frac14$$
